# How to create multiples of line-height in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, css

I am still new to Javascript and JQuery. I have written a small function I run from document-ready. Its purpose is to set the height of a div as a multiple of line-heights:

```
function setLoginLinksHeight(numOfLines) {

    var ll = hash(LOGIN_LINKS);
    $(ll).css('line-height','130%');
    var lh = $(ll).css('line-height');
    var nh = lh * numOfLines; // Issue here
    $(ll).height(nh);

}
```

From FireBug, the line-height I retrieve is `15.5833px`. When I multiply it by 2 (for example), `nh` is set to `NaN`. I saw in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185151/how-to-determine-a-line-height-using-javascript-jquery) that the retrieved value can have any format (%, px, etc...). This is scary!

How can I convert the returned value into a number of pixels without units into order to be able to create multiples of it? Is there a library/function available for this in Javascript or JQuery? What is the recommended practice in this case? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have developed a small unit splitter following mblase75's solution:

```
function splitUnit(e) {

    var eUnit = '';
    var eValue;

    if( e && ( length = e.search( /px/ ) ) ) {
        eUnit = 'px';
        eValue = e.substr( 0, length );
    } else if ( e && ( length = e.search( /em/ ) ) ) {
        eUnit = 'em';
        eValue = e.substr( 0, length );
    } else {
        eValue = e;
    }

    return new Array( eValue, eUnit );

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
var lh = parseFloat($(ll).css('line-height'));
```

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that you'll be getting a number of pixels, just that you'll be getting a number. To extract the units separately, add:

```
var lhunits = $(ll).css('line-height').match(/\D+$/)[0]; 
// gets first element of array
```

...and then combine the calculation with the old units:

```
var nh = (lh*numOfLines) + lhunits;
```

Comment: The parseFloat() works, but the unit extraction returns 'x', instead of 'px' (says FireBug).

Comment: @JVerstry Ah, I should have thought of that. Fixed now.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I was working on creating a small unit splitter too (see update in my question).

Answer (score 1):

var test = "15.83333px";

alert(parseFloat(test));

Just tried this in jsFiddle.  Worked as expected and returned the value without pixels