# Is particular x-y coordinate in between lines of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

How can one tell, using Javascript (jQuery will work), if a particular X-Y coordinate on an HTML page is vertically between two lines of text? The lines may be in the middle of a long paragraph, inside a lengthy line-item tag, in a span, between two tags, etc. I have no way of controlling the HTML or the X-Y point, but I need to know if the X-Y point is in the middle of a line of text, or if it is in-between two lines of text; and it needs to be pretty efficient.

Please ask any questions you may have if I have not been clear enough.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well first of all id recommend establish a consitent baseline grid, thats going to ease your calculation tremendously. Blueprintcss will give you this out of the box (960.gs will not), or you could create your own http://www.alistapart.com/articles/settingtypeontheweb

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.getBoundingClientRect()` on a text range.  You will need to write separate code for IE vs Non-IE browsers to get the text ranges.

This should be relatively easy in IE, thanks to [`textRange.moveToPoint(x, y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536632%28VS.85%29.aspx).  For other browsers you'll have to do something like do a binary search on the elements in the DOM, calling `.getBoundingClientRect()` on the elements, until you find the element that contains your text.  Then create a range that contains the text of that element and do a binary search on the range to find whether your point overlaps any text.

All of this will be greatly complicated if you have absolutely positioned elements with text overlapping other elements.

Comment: You can utilize [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) instead of writing separate code for IE vs. non-IE : )

Answer (score 1):

Having dealt with text ranges, I don't think you can technically put anything "between" two lines of text on the same HTML node. Even if you use line height, every pixel belongs to one of the lines (even though it's visually space between them).

I'll throw out a few options which might help.

The simplest answer is probably just to use the line height:
get dom element that was clicked (event.relatedTarget in jQuery?)
determine its offset relative to the page (i.e. where the top of that element is)
determine the point that was clicked (x,y coords of the mouse event)
compare the two using the [line-height of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185151/how-to-determine-a-line-height-using-javascript-jquery) in the row

This would look something like this:

```
function getLines(topOfElement, clickPoint, lineHeight) {
   return Math.floor( (clickPoint - topOfElement)/lineHeight );
}

var topOfElement = $(element).offset().top; //must be position: relative|absolute
var clickedPoint = event.clientY; //might be pageY?
var lineHeight = parseFloat($(element).css('line-height')); //probably need to set this in px using css or it might be null
var textHeight = parseInt($(element).css('font-size')); //probably need to set this in px using css or it might be null
var prevLineNumber = getLines(topOfElement, clickedPoint, lineHeight);

// the previous line ends (in theory) at the bottom of the text (textHeight)
// you might need to adjust this definition to your needs
var prevLineBottom = prevLineNumber*lineHeight+topOfElement+textHeight;

// the next line begins (in theory) at the top of its line
// you might need to adjust this definition to your needs
var nextLineTop = (prevLineNumber+1)+lineHeight;

if( clickedPoint >= nextLineTop ) {
   alert('clicked on row '+(prevLineNumber+1));
}
else if( clickedPoint <= prevLineBottom ) {
   alert('clicked on row '+prevLineNumber);
}
else {
   alert('clicked between rows '+prevLineNumber+' and '+(prevLineNumber+1));
}
```

If you want to see if the click happened between two html nodes, you can do that with [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/), as well as some fancy selection and range calculations.

You could use it for things like determining the exact length of the text before and after the seletion. This is only useful if you want to see where in the text they clicked.

```
function getTextAtClick() {
   var result = {nodeClicked: null, textBefore: '', textAfter: '', valid: false};

   //get a selection object (even though the selection is technically zero length)
   var sel = rangy.getSelection(); 

   //you would probably want to discard any selection not zero length (i.e actual selection of text instead of a click)
   // if not, you'd need to decide what it means to select across multiple dom nodes :(
   if( sel.toString().length > 0 ) { return result; }

   // get the point where the click occurred
   var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
   result.valid = true;

   // determine text in our dom element up to the click point
   var before = rangy.createRange();
   before.setStart(range.startContainer, 0);
   before.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
   result.textBefore = before.toString();

   // determine text in our dom element after the click point
   var after = rangy.createRange();
   after.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset+1);
   after.setEndAfter(range.startContainer);
   result.textAfter = after.toString();

   return result;
}
```