# How to get a textarea line-height in IE6/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

is there any way can get a textarea line-height(i want a number of px,not a string such as "normal") in IE6/7?

Comment: Also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185151/how-to-determine-a-line-height-using-javascript-jquery).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't have IE6 but if you're using jquery this should work

```
$('textarea').css('line-height');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3rd8/

Comment: In IE7 a string with the content `normal` will be returned. And this is the problem.