# jQuery and line-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Oh yes, yet another question about this rule.
So what we have here? 
If i use jQuery to get line-height like this:

```
$elm.css('lineHeight')
```

i always get back the value that has been computed, for example 20px. It is from font-size 10 and 2 line-height.

But if i get the line-height this way:

```
elm.style.lineHeight
```

i get the real value that wasn't been computed

The question is - how i can get the value of the line-height rule WITH jQuery? Why jQuery returns me the computed value!?

Comment: Because jQuery's `.css` method uses the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method  behind the scenes . But why everything has to be in jQuery?

Comment: Thx
Just for clean code) I think if i use the jquery i need to use it as much as possible. Otherwise i need to remove the library because it is not useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elem.style` just return the declared inline style of one element not the actual applied style. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

> The style property is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the `<head>` section, or external style sheets. To get the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use `window.getComputedStyle()` instead.

jQuery.css() returns the computed style

> Description: Get the computed style properties for the first element in the set of matched elements.

To get the inline style with jQuery you have to query the attributes via `attr('style')`.

You could use a function like this:(http://andreknieriem.de/jquery-checken-ob-ein-element-ein-bestimmtes-inline-style-attribut-hat/)

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
     var styles = this.attr("style"),
         value;
     styles && styles.split(";").forEach(function (e) {
         var style = e.split(":");
         if ($.trim(style[0]) === prop) {
             value = style[1];           
         }                    
     });   
     return value;
};
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) .css() returns computed style CSS properties. This is done intentionally, as the property you get directly (elm.style.lineHeight) isn't cross-browser and can come in whatever form the browser want to give it to you (% or whatever).

If you for some reason need to get the exact value of the property, simply don't use css(). Just pull the style out of DOM and work with it.

However, you should really consider your goals. If it is the inconsistencies in css('lineHeight') that are bothering you, you can try something like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185151/how-to-determine-a-line-height-using-javascript-jquery):

```
var fontSize = $(el).css('font-size');
var lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(fontSize.replace('px','')) * 1.5);
```

This evades most of the computation that might be giving you trouble. Just determine the constant (1.5 implies 0.5 inter-line intervals) and you should get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The .css() method in jquery runs the

```
getComputedStyle()
```

method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer.

Different browsers may return computed style values that are logically but not textually equal. The computed style of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as `em, ex, px or %` in a style sheet.

For getting the computed value via javascript use :

`window.getComputedStyle(ele);`