# How can I get absolute line-height when it set to 'normal'?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this:

```
<p id="p1" style="line-height:normal">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

and I need to increment line-height one pixel.
How can I get absolute line-height when it set to 'normal'?

```
ar lh=$('#paraph').css('line-height');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine a 'line-height' using Javascript (jQuery)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185151/how-to-determine-a-line-height-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I write this code and it's work properly in chrome

```
$('#lineHeightInc')
    .click(function() {
        var box = GetSelectedBox();
        var ct = box.data('LineHeight');
        if (isNaN(ct))
            ct = 0;
        ct++;
        box.css('line-height', (parseFloat(box.css('font-size')) * 1.61 + ct) + 'px');
        box.data('LineHeight', ct);
    });
$('#lineHeightDic')
    .click(function () {
        var box = GetSelectedBox();
        var ct = box.data('LineHeight');
        if (isNaN(ct))
            ct = 0;
        ct--;
        box.css('line-height', (parseFloat(box.css('font-size')) * 1.61 + ct) + 'px');
        box.data('LineHeight', ct);
    });
```

If any one has better solution I would be happy to know that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for you just change the line-height to 100% and try this:

HTML:

```
<p id="p1" style="line-height:100%">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
var lh = $('#p1').css('line-height');
$('#p1').css('line-height', parseFloat(lh, 10) + 1 + 'px');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7yf43j43/8/

Comment: @MohammadReza  "normal" string as returned value can't pars to float number!

Comment: it's not working on chrome but it's fine on firefox. @NaserYousefi

Comment: @HassanALi is it possible for you to change the line-height  to 100%?

Comment: Thank you Reza but my question is very clear. How can I get absolute line-height when it set to 'normal'? Where Did the 100% Come From?

Comment: @NaserYousefi With 'normal' it doesn't work on chrome.