# Remove separator (":before") on a new line

Tags: jquery, css

I am using this code to add a separator between menu items.

```
li:before {
    content: '\00B7';
    float: left;
}
```

There's any way to remove the separator if I go to a new line?
See picture (I want to remove the dot before "Test category 2")

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to provide a definite solution without having seen your HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i is what you need and combine it with dynamic css!

Comment: Basically...NO. CSS can't detect where an element's content will wrap. You need JS....or a reasonable set of media queries.

Comment: @Thomas this is a good hint in what I want to achieve - Thank you, and thanks to you all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can combine CSS pseudo-classes like `:nth-child` or `:last-child` to do something like:

```
li:last-child:before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
}
```

or if it's the third to last

```
li:nth-last-child(3):before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
}
```

Then, you could maybe combine this with media queries.