# How to get the current upper and lower line boundaries of an inline element?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

For instance :

```
<div>
<span style="font-size: 20pt" id="BBB">Hello</span> 
<span style="font-size: 5pt; vertical-align: middle;" id="AAA">World</span> 
</div>
```

From the element BBB it's easy to get the line boundaries as BBB is the taller element of the line. Its offsetTop and offsetHeight properties are the line boundaries.

But how to get the line boundaries from the element AAA ?

Can I get that info directly, or do I have to loop through the elements of the line ?

Comment: What do you mean by *get the line boundaries*? Can you give an example of what result you expect, and what you tried to get it?

Comment: The top and bottom y values of the line. In my example that would be the top and bottom values of the first element as it is the bigger one.

Comment: `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Nope that gives the boundaries of the element, not of the line.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe you could use Selection API to create a selection range for the line, and then use `Range.getBoundingClientRect()`. Might be easier to loop through the line though.

Comment: Yes I think there is no magical function that will help here.

Comment: So what about `Element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: it will not work with multiple lines inside the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to handle line boxes.

There was that question related : 
[How can I count text lines inside an DOM element? Can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i)

And no miracle there.

Answer (score 0):

use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get all the computed `css` properties for the rendered element and pick what you want.

> The **Window.getComputedStyle()** method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

i noticed that in the snippet there are not all the properties so check this  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdpy1azp/24/)

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#AAA');
const computed = window.getComputedStyle(element);

[...computed].forEach((e) => {
  console.log(e, ' : ', computed.getPropertyValue(e));
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="font-size: 20pt">Hello </span>
  <span style="font-size: 5pt; display: middle;" id="AAA">World </span>
  <span style="font-size: 10pt">etc </span>
  <span style="font-size: 10pt">etc</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't find the info in there.