# How to return number of lines for a p element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, paragraph

Consider the p element below.

```
<p>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm 122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999</p>
```

In my current screen-size, in my particular browser, it took 3 whole lines to type this piece of html code inside the checkbox element in which I am typing this question.

Now if this were a p element in a real html page, the number of lines would have depended on multiple factors such as font-size, font-family, letter-spacing, font-weight, number of characters, viewport width, the browser, etc.

Is there any javascript method or css rule to return the number of lines for a particular p element in a particular browser for a particular screen size?

I mean how can we check the number of lines when the p elemnt is loaded if we want to do something with that number such as store it in a variable or use it in an if statement?

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i

Comment: Calculate the height of a p with one line and then the height of the actual content. Devide and you have the approximate lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count text lines inside an DOM element? Can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i)

Comment: A <p> element will have a set amount of padding/margin top and bottom, irrespective of the number of lines. - so simple division by the height of a single line paragraph won't really work.  I'm not sure why you need the number of lines - it would be a lot easier to get the height, deduct the standard padding/margin amount - and what's left is the text height.  You could equate this easily enough to a number of lines, or just save it as a means of comparing the content height of various <p> elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple calculation of element height divided by line height can give you the number of lines rendered on actual display.

```
// 1. get height of element.
// 2. get line height.
// 3. divide 1 by 2 to figure out computed lines.

function countLines(element) {

    let x = $(element).prop('scrollHeight');
    let y = $(element).css('lineHeight');
    y = parseInt(y);

    return x/y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By counting line breaks it's possible using javascript,check my code below

```
function lineBreakCount(str){
/* counts \n */
try {
    return((str.match(/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/gi).length));
} catch(e) {
    return 0;
}
}
```