# Reduce font-size based on number of div lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, I wanted the font to be reduced based on the number of lines in the div and from a start size. **(Each line reduces the font)**.

The function below is all I have and works based on the height of the div.

```
$.fn.resizeText = function (options) {  

    var settings = $.extend({ maxfont: 40, minfont: 17 }, options);

    var style = $('<style>').html('.nodelays ' +
    '{ ' +
        '-moz-transition: none !important; ' +
        '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
        '-o-transition: none !important; ' +
        'transition: none !important;' +
    '}');

    function shrink(el, fontsize, minfontsize)
    {
        if (fontsize < minfontsize) return;

        el.style.fontSize = fontsize + 'px';            

        if (el.scrollHeight > el.closest(".container").offsetHeight) shrink(el, fontsize - 1, minfontsize);
    }

    $('head').append(style);

    $(this).each(function(index, el)
    {
        var element = $(el);

        element.addClass('nodelays');

        shrink(el, settings.maxfont, settings.minfont);

        element.removeClass('nodelays');
    });

    style.remove();
}
```

Comment: If you know line height doesn't the height of the div give you what you need? Are other elements existing other than text in div? You really haven't specified what the specific problem is with code shown....or defined explicitly how lines should be determined....or what expected results are

Comment: @charlietfl Text only. The code works but based on the height of the div, I want it to resize every line the div has.

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve]. We have no idea what other style rules are applied or what expected results are or what should be different than what is shown

Comment: You can find the number of line with this function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i

Answer (score 0):

The size you are looking for is relative to the font family, because it is not always the same number of lines if they are tested with different fonts in the same text. using the following solution:

[How can I count text lines inside an DOM element? Can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783936/11781277)

This is an approximate solution, taking into account a maximum number of lines

```html
<body>
  <div id="content" style="width: 80px; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px; visibility: hidden;">
    hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you? how are you? how are you? how are you?
  </div>
  <script>
  function countLines(elm) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elm);
    var divHeight = el.offsetHeight;
    var lineHeight = parseInt(el.style.lineHeight);
    var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
    return lines;
  }

  var max_lines = 10;

  function auto_size_text(elm) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elm);
    var lines = countLines(elm);
    var size = parseInt(el.style.fontSize.replace("px", ""));
    if(lines > max_lines) {
       size--;
       el.style.fontSize = size + "px";
       el.style.lineHeight = size + "px";
       auto_size_text(elm);
    }
  }

  function show_div (elm) {
     var el = document.getElementById(elm);
     el.style.visibility = "";
  }
  auto_size_text("content");
  show_div("content");
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: One problem: it only reduces if the number of lines is greater than the maximum, I wanted it to reduce each line, do you know how to solve? But thanks for the reply anyway.